# How to get substring in SQLIte?

Tags: database, sqlite

I retrieve quite a lot of data from SQLite database. When retrieving I map it to different views in my application. There is a text field in my table from which I don't want to get the full text, just first n chars. So if my query for example is:

```
Select description from articles where id='29';
```

Then how do I get the substring from description? thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the `substr` function.

From the [list of core functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

> `substr(X,Y,Z) substr(X,Y) substring(X,Y,Z) substring(X,Y)`
>
> The `substr(X,Y,Z)` function returns a substring of input string `X` that
> begins with the `Y-th` character and which is `Z` characters long. If `Z` is
> omitted then `substr(X,Y)` returns all characters through the end of the
> string `X` beginning with the `Y-th`. The left-most character of `X` is
> number 1. If `Y` is negative then the first character of the substring
> is found by counting from the right rather than the left. If `Z` is
> negative then the `abs(Z)` characters preceding the `Y-th` character are
> returned. If `X` is a string then characters indices refer to actual
> UTF-8 characters. If `X` is a BLOB then the indices refer to bytes.
>
> `substring()` is an alias for `substr()` beginning with SQLite version
> 3.34.

Answer (score 22):

### **To get the substring in SQLite**

You can use the builtin function in SQLite which is `substr(X,Y,Z)`. The x field represents the string input to be sliced, the y field represents the starting point using an index, and the z field represents the substring length.

```
===============================
|Database Table : **articles**|
===============================
|id | description             |
-------------------------------
|29 | Lorem ipsum domit       |
===============================
```

Now we will try to make a select query for our description

```
SELECT substr(description,1,4) FROM articles where id='29';
```

Output would be: **Lore** instead of Lorem ipsum domit

Answer (score 1):

To extend existing answers, starting from [SQLite 3.34.0](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_34_0.html):

> The substr() SQL function can now also be called "substring()" for compatibility with SQL Server.

> [substring(X,Y)](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr)
> "substring()" is an alias for "substr()" beginning with SQLite version 3.34.